# how to fetch user details from populated table in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

I have two tables in my MongoDB cluster i.e Post and User. Actually I want to retrieve the username and userID along with a post from the post table when a user posts something.

**my post controller**

```
router.getPostsList = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.list();
    return res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json(err);
  }

};
```

**MongoDB Post collection Image**

[image]

**PostSchema**

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    text: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true
    },
    user: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
      }
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: You can either a) make a consecutive query for all of the associated users after getting their IDs from the post records, then join the records in JavaScript (normalized model) or b) actually store the username in each post record when it is created (denormalized model)